# Solid State Disk (SSD) Disappeared After Power Failure

Tags: ssd

I was using Intel Smart Response Technology (using SSD for caching HDD). After a sudden power failure, both BIOS screens and Windows boots become very slow. After checking about whats wrong, I realized the SSD had completely disappeared from both the BIOS screen and Windows. I tried to take-out the SSD and plug it in again but it didn't help.

What can I try? Is there a possibility that a SSD can die from a single power failure?

Edit:
I tried it on another computer but nothing changed. No matter what i do SSd doesn't recognised. I gave it to technical service, they said drive is dead.

Corsair f60 60gb SSD died from a single power failure :(

As a result, i bought a new one. Of course not from Corsair.

Comment: You need to run some diagnostics, otherwise we're not really able to help you! Maybe you should read the man pages or documentation of things like gparted and `dmesg`. Without diagnostic information this Question might stay unanswered!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the manufacturer of your SSD, he might actually supply software for more in-depth diagnostics of your SSD. My SSD "disappeared" just like that one day (while the machine was working).

Booting off USB stick and checking what SATA drivers said, clarified it as a controller failure.

I suggest you boot linux off USB drive or DVD and use `dmesg` to check what's going on. I'd suggest using [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php), [SysRrecCD](http://www.sysresccd.org/), or [Knoppix](http://www.knoppix.org/), those live distros have tools for checking / repairing partitions, etc.

Comment: Tried Gparted and Knoppix, both didn't see SSD. :/

Comment: What do you mean "didn't see SSD", what did `dmesg` say? Does yout ATA controller sense the disc, but partitions are broken? Or is the controller not responding on sensing the SATA connect signal?

Comment: On Gparted i only saw partitions which are on my HDD. Didnt' see anything about SSD. When i type "dmesg" the only message that draw my attention is "Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND". I don't know if this message related with SSD. I'm not expert, ı hardly understand the results of "dmesg" command.

Comment: I suggest hotplugging your SSD and then checing what dmesg does. SATA supports hot plugging, so no worries. Just boot with the SSD not attached, then attach the signal cable (keep power attached). Run dmesg before and after, and see what changes.

Comment: "dmesg" result before attaching SSD : http://pastebin.ca/2441322      "dmesg" result after attached SSD : http://pastebin.ca/2441323

Comment: Changed lines : 1391.
[ 1177.925192] ata1: exception Emask 0x50 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4090800 action 0xe frozen

1392.
[ 1177.925197] ata1: irq_stat 0x00400040, connection status changed

1393.
[ 1177.925201] ata1: SError: { HostInt PHYRdyChg 10B8B DevExch }

1394.
[ 1177.925210] ata1: hard resetting link

COMRESET failed (errno=-16)

1389.
[  519.576498] ata1: reset failed, giving up

Comment: I read in another site about "exception Emask 0x50 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4090800 action 0xe frozen" error, it may be result of bad Sata cable. But i tried connecting my HDD using SDD's sata cable and HDD is working fine. So, i think it s not about SATA cable.

Comment: You can try another SATA port on your mainboard, but to me, it looks like the controller on the SATA disk is damaged. If the SSD manufacturer provides some extra tools, you can try them as a last resort, otherwise, the disk is damaged beyond repair. You might still file a guarantee issue, though.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had the same problem with my Crucial 250 GB. My Asus z97 Pro did not detect it. I shut down the power and waited a minute or so then, everything works well.

Looks like it is a new industry, relatively speaking, and hopefully somebody will find a solution to it.